# relative path method to read external json file with jquery

Tags: javascript, json

As showen on title I want to read a json file in jquery with relative path method. First of all, I am a beginer on this job and it's can be stupid thing which I try.

I have a external json file, I want to turned this file in my script. json file must have a external because of, can changed by somereason after developing and its will be regular changing according to process.

here is the my json file.

```
{
    "revisiondate": "21 April 2016",
    "documentname": "1658MC",
    "department": "Sales",
    "description": "Available",
    "link": "href=1658MC.pdf"
}, {
    "revisiondate": "16 April 2016",
    "documentname": "VCX16B",
    "department": "Enginnering",
    "description": "Not Available",
    "link": "href=VCX16B.pdf"
}, {
    "revisiondate": "15 March 2016",
    "documentname": "AB36F",
    "department": "Custumer Services",
    "description":  "Not Available",
    "link": "href=AB36F.pdf"
}, {
    "revisiondate": "12 Agust 2016",
    "documentname": "FC25D",
    "department": "Technical Support",
    "description": "Not Available",
    "link": "href=FC25D.pdf"
}
```

And this json file saved into my local file

```
C:.......\Desktop\Deneme16\Deneme161.json
```

To read this file with my script

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <table id="userdata" border="0.02">
                <th>Revision  Date</th>
                <th>Document  Name</th>
                <th>Department </th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Link</th>               
        </table>
    <script>    
    $.ready(function() {    
    myObjects = {};
        $.getJSON('deneme16.json', function(data) {
        myObjects.myJson = data;
          }); 
    $.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
                var tblRow =    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate + 
                                "</td><td>" + person.documentname + 
                                "</td><td>" + person.department +
                                "</td><td>" + person.description + 
                                "</td><td><a target='_blank' href='"
+ person.link.split('href=')[1]
+"' >"+person.link.split('href=')[1]
+"</a></td></tr>"

                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });     

         });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I read this local file with jquery? I read a lot of tittle but some title talking about ajax.request someones talking about parse.jquery and someones talknig about it is not possible because of security policty. I tried a lot of thing and finally I decided to write that codes. I am really confused and I want to solve this problem. Can someone explaşn where is the problem to oparete this code

Comment: have you get data using getJSON , console.log(data) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ready(function() {    
    myObjects = {};

    $.getJSON('deneme16.json', function(data) {

        myObjects.myJson = data;

        //you cant acces data outside the getJSON function
        $.each(data, function(i, person) {
            var tblRow =    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate + 
            "</td><td>" + person.documentname + 
            "</td><td>" + person.department +
            "</td><td>" + person.description + 
            "</td><td><a target='_blank' href='"
            + person.link.split('href=')[1]
            +"' >"+person.link.split('href=')[1]
            +"</a></td></tr>"

            $("#userdata tbody").append(tblRow);
        });     
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Surucundeki dosyalara javascript ile erisemezsin. Guvenlik acigi nedeniyle hemen hemen butun browserlardan kaldirildi. Ajax ile server'daki dosyalara erisip, JSON.parse(jsonString) seklinde okuyabilirsin.

Comment: Eyvallah. Bulamadım hiç  örnek felan. Denicem yine bişeyler. Sağol tavsiyen için.

Answer (score -1):

**Firstly** your JSON is incorrect, it should be either an array (that's your case. I have corrected it [here](http://myjson.com/1djve3)) or it should have only one parent object. You are having 4 parent objects.

**Secondly**, you are incorrectly trying to iterate your JSON response from your getJSON request. It should be done inside callback function otherwise your iterative code is executed without waiting for the data to be iterated.

Check below snippet, it is working. I have just printed fetched values to console. You can reformat using your above code to append data in table.

**Also**, if your local json file get request throws 'Cross origin' error, then try to host your JSON on some web storage like this one - [http://myjson.com](http://myjson.com/1djve3)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    myObjects = [];
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1djve3', function(data) {
        myObjects = Object.values(data);
        console.log("Objects in array " + myObjects.length);
        
         $.each(myObjects, function(i, person) {
              
              
       var $row = $('<tr>'+
      '<td>'+person.revisiondate+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+person.documentname+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+person.department+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+person.description+'</td>'+
       '<td>'+person.link.split("=")[1]+'</td>'+
      '</tr>');    

$('table> tbody:last').append($row);
              
            }); 
          }); 
       

         });
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <table id="userdata" border="0.02">
                <th>Revision  Date</th>
                <th>Document  Name</th>
                <th>Department </th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Link</th>               
        </table>
    <script>    
  
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction.Uploading  json on a url can be use effectivetly but I couldn't turned that code on fiddle and my computer. What is the difference between fiddle.net and this page's snippet?

Comment: what do you mean by - I coundn't turned that code on fiddle and my computer?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't work as it seems on your comment.

Comment: here you go - I have created a fiddle for you -https://jsfiddle.net/manapat/j6wq2747/

Comment: Also updated the code here in this snippet. Problem was I was displaying result in console, but I guess you didn't checked the console. Now, I am displaying in table (the way you originally wanted). Please accept the answer if it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: You are great. Actually I tried very much but your way is very different than mine. Thanks a lot. I tried to a lot of thing to get local json file with relative path like c:/path/...to/.json. But for some policy this is not possible as I understand. Do you have  any idea about this?

Comment: Here is the related bug for that https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787
`file:/// ` protocol doesn't work with getJson api

Comment: Just in case if you really want to read local json file, then use this api https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-filereader